# Genymotion android animation glitch?

Tags: android-studio, genymotion, window-managers

I'm running a genymotion android 8.0 emulator and whenever i try to animate a view or set its translationX it kind of does this where the apple is the view and it just repeats itself to the desired translation.
[image]

My View is inside a relative layout on the windowmanager and all my animations work fine on any other emulator except the 8.0 ones. It even works fine on my real phone. Is this a bug or some new feature in Api 26 I'm not aware of?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ah the problem was I forgot to include PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT in my layout params my bad